# How to make a node only overhear neighbor's packets and itself doesn't send or forward any packets?

Tags: iot, packet, contiki, cooja

I want to make a node which can overhear neighbor's sending packets and print the information of the packet in Mote output cooja. And I also hope the node doesn't send or forward any packets. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a sniffer. Check out `examples/sensniff` for an example on how to implement that.

To go into more detail, you most likely need to disable the network layers above radio (use "nullnet") with `MAKE_NET=MAKE_NET_NULLNET` and implement a custom MAC layer, like the SenSniff example does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,kfx. I try to use examples/sensniff and use sensniff.c to compile in cooja. I don't understand the output. Such as <@@raApz;:   <@@rLazz3:@  rraAz;:  Could you tell more?

Comment: And I write a sniffer by myself. I use input_packet function in it.It could printf the packets of neighbors.But it also send packets.How can I make it doesn't send any packets?

Comment: @kgao I think you have to use tools/sensniff to convert the output to PCAP. Look at the README files for more info.

Comment: With nullnet it not send any packets.

Comment: Thanks!Contiki-NG has Nullnet, but contiki-3.0 not?

Comment: The sniffer example also exists in Contiki 3.x (not sure if in 3.0), it should not send packed.